# IPv6 regex for extraction in event processing

Tags: ipv6, complex-event-processing

I need to extract an IP address from a log message to identify the cause of the issue.

I am using this complex event processing from dataanalytics360.com

The current system is having a regex to extract the ipv4 address which is

```
^.* (([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})) .*$
```

What should be the regex to extract an ipv6 address. I need to extract the hexadecimals but when I saw examples it shows something in "/" formats also. what does the "/" signify.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Chris

Comment: The / notation in IP addresses (both IPv4 and IPv6) is the prefix length. It shows the number of bits in the address that are 'fixed' for the subnet. So bigger numbers mean smaller subnets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out these 4 options

you will have to write them one by one.. and which ever regex matches .. it will yield the extracted values. you can write them all in a single parsing rule or create separate rule for each match

strIPv6Pattern  = "\A(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}\z"

strIPv6Pattern_HEXCompressed  = "\A((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})*)?)::((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})*)?)\z"

StrIPv6Pattern_6Hex4Dec = "\A((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6,6})(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\z"

StrIPv6Pattern_Hex4DecCompressed  = "\A((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}(?::[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})*)?) ::((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:)*)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)(.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[0-1]?\d?\d)){3}\z"